# What are the stats for an Armor of Fortification?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, armor

According to the D&D 3.5E rules, can anyone confirm whether Armor of Fortification (light) item would correspond to light armor?

If so, which light armor...a chain shirt maybe? If not, is armor of fortification (light) some kind of magical enhancement you add to your current armor?

Sorry if I seem a bit confused, I didn't find anything about that in the 3.5E PHB.

While playing a Roll20 DnD game, my DM gave me this item as a reward. My human paladin currently wears full plate (armor type: heavy, AC bonus +8, max dex +1, check penalty -6). So, if my paladin chooses to equip an Armor of Fortification (light), will it have the same stats as a masterwork chain shirt (type: light armor, AC: +4, max dex bonus: +4, armor check penalty: -2+1=-1) + the 25% chance of negating crit damage and sneak attack damage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fortification](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Fortification) is a magical enhancement.

> This suit of armor or shield produces a magical force that protects vital areas of the wearer more effectively. When a critical hit or sneak attack is scored on the wearer, there is a chance that the critical hit or sneak attack is negated and damage is instead rolled normally.
>
> ```
> Fortification Type  Chance for Normal Damage
> Light               25%
> Moderate            75%
> Heavy               100%
> ```

The base armor could be any type. It needs to be [magic armor](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Magic_Armor#Magic_Armor), ie, have at least a +1 bonus.

> In addition to an enhancement bonus, armor may have special abilities. Special abilities usually count as additional bonuses for determining the market value of an item, but do not improve AC. A suit of armor cannot have an effective bonus (enhancement plus special ability bonus equivalents) higher than +10. **A suit of armor with a special ability must have at least a +1 enhancement bonus.**

You'll need to ask your DM for more details on your specific armour.

Comment: Just like to add, in case his DM doesn't realize, Light Fortification = +1 Bonus, Moderate Fortification = +3 Bonus, and Heavy Fortification = +5 Bonus.

Comment: @Ruut Yes, I left that column out, as I'm _assuming_ the DM knows what he's doing, and it's not something the player needs to worry about. It only affects cost/availability, it doesn't give an _actual_ AC bonus.

Comment: I want to agree with you my good man.

Comment: Right, I found this info in the 3.5 PHB a few days ago but still had this doubt. Guess I'll have to talk to my DM about this too. And from what I understood according to the PHB, +1 bonus affects armor check penalty, not AC. Thanks for the input.

Comment: oops, +1 bonus is -1 armor check penalty and also base price modifier +1 ;)

Comment: @Ghengra Fortification doesn't affect armor check penalty, that stays the same as it was for the type of armor. The _only_ effect Fortification has (other than costing more) is what's in my answer above.

Comment: I saw this in the 3.5E PHB (p. 126, "masterwork armor" section) "Such a well made item functions like the normal version, except that its armor check penalty is lessened by 1. For example, a masterwork chain shirt has an armor check penatly of -1 rather than -2"... and later..."All magic armors and shield are automatically considered to be of masterwork quality."

Comment: Yes OK, but that's independent of the Fortification. The armor _also_ needs to have a + bonus as well as the Fortification... I'll add that to my answer... (something else to ask your DM)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you or your DM may be a little confused as to what the (light) in that block of information means. The "light" corresponds to the level of Fortification, not the type of armor. Fortification can be placed on any masterwork suit of armor or shield. You could have +1 Chain Shirt of Light Fortification just as same as you could have +2 Chain Shirt of Heavy Fortification.

The level of Fortification is the percentage chance that the ability in question nullifies a critical hit or a sneak attack. "Light" has a 25% chance of negating critical damage or sneak attacks. "Moderate" has a 75% chance, and "Heavy" makes you immune to critical damage and sneak attacks.